# Getting count of last records of 2 columns SQL

Tags: sql

I was looking for a solution for the below mentioned scenario.
So my table structure is like this ;  Table name : energy_readings

| equipment_id | meter_id | readings | reading_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 01/01/2022 |
| 1 | 1 | 200 | 02/01/2022 |
| 1 | 1 | null | 03/01/2022 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 | 01/01/2022 |
| 1 | 2 | null | 04/01/2022 |
| 2 | 1 | null | 04/01/2022 |
| 2 | 1 | 399 | 05/01/2022 |
| 2 | 2 | null | 02/01/2022 |

So from this , I want to get the number of nulls for the **last record of same equipment_id and meter_id.** (Should only consider the nulls of the last record of same equipment_id and meter_id)

EX : Here , the last reading for equipment 1 and meter 1 is a null , therefore it should be considered for the count. Also the last reading(Latest Date) for equipment 1 and meter 2 is a null , should be considered for count. But even though  equipment 2 and meter 1 has a null , it is not the last record (Latest Date) , therefore should not be considered for the count.

Thus , this should be the result ;

| equipment_id | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

Hope I was clear with the question.
Thank you!

Comment: There is no "first" or "last" reading in your table without a column which keeps track of that.  Please edit your table and include this column.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen , Thanks for the attention , I have edited the question , hope it is fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CTE` like below. CTE `LatestRecord` will get latest record for equipment_id & meter_id. Later you can join it with your current table and use `WHERE` to filter out record with `null` values only.

```
;WITH LatestRecord AS (
    SELECT equipment_id, meter_id, MAX(reading_date) AS reading_date
    FROM energy_readings
    GROUP BY equipment_id, meter_id
)
SELECT er.meter_id, COUNT(1) AS [Count]
FROM energy_readings er
    JOIN LatestRecord lr
        ON lr.equipment_id = er.equipment_id
            AND lr.meter_id = er.meter_id
            AND lr.reading_date = er.reading_date
WHERE er.readings IS NULL
GROUP BY er.meter_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with records as(
select equ_id,meter_id,reading_date,readings,
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY meter_id,equ_id
            order by reading_date) Count

from equipment order by equ_id
)

select equ_id,count(counter)
from
(

select  equ_id,meter_id,reading_date,readings,MAX(Count) as counter
from records                      
 group by meter_id,equ_id 
 order by equ_id
 ) where readings IS NULL group by equ_id
```

Explanation:-

1. records will order data by reading_date and will give counting as 1,2,3..
2. select max of count from records
3. select count of counter where reading is null

[Partition by will give counting as shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMveI.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAixD.png)